# Mac / Cocoa - Process Independent of user

Tags: macos, cocoa, background

I have one cocoa program (I built it as an app, but none of it needs to be an app, it could be a command line tool), that I need to start on boot, and remain running till shutdown, regardless of if the user logs out.

Is this possible, preferably non-root?

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a system level [launchd daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). You have to [create a launchd plist file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-104142-BCICCCFI) and install it to either **/System/Library/LaunchDaemons** or **/Library/LaunchDaemons**. Since you mentioned that you want the daemon to be running at all times until shutdown, you'll want to set the `KeepAlive` option to `true` in your property list file.